# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when using this short program to Remove title bar

Tags: java, matlab, fullscreen, heap-memory

I found this piece of code on stackoverflow for displaying a fullscreen colour in MATLAB:
[Remove titlebar from MATLAB GUI for full screen display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082896/remove-titlebar-from-matlab-gui-for-full-screen-display)

The problem is that once I've run the program 5 times, there is an error that shows up:

> ??? Java exception occurred: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space" error that shows up.

Now, I could increase heap space like it is described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18I2C/index.html)

But since my application has to run for long periods of time, is there a way I can clear the heapspace each time the script is run? 
In this way, I won't have to allocate more heapspace memory and have that run out eventually as well.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: Possibly your figures aren't being deleted and you have a memory leak somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always just do a "clear java" if you don't mind blowing away everything.