# Making a fullscreen movie in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, fullscreen, movie

So I'm trying to make a movie on MATLAB that contains some grey circles at specific locations, with one of the circles going from black to white over the course of it. However I can't get it to only record the images over the whole screen at the right resolution instead of showing it in a figure window. Here's what I've got so far:

```
h=ones(1080,1920);
trap1=.5*circ(1920,1080,55,532,534,2);
trap2=.5*circ(1920,1080,55,528,798,2);
pcf=circ(1920,1080,18,1520,504,2); %Makes the circles


for ii=1:256
    pcfl=pcf*(ii-1)/255; %Steps through greylevels
    m=h.*(trap1+trap2+pcfl); %Make everything but the circles black    
    hfig=imshow(m); %Display image
    colormap('gray') %This is probably unnecessary
    mov(ii)=getframe(gcf);
end

myVideo = VideoWriter('trapmov.avi');
open(myVideo);
writeVideo(myVideo,mov)
close(myVideo)
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082896/remove-titlebar-from-matlab-gui-for-full-screen-display) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23404) which seem close to what I want (esp. the second one), but I don't know enough about java to be able to make a movie from the first one, and the second one doesn't work because it claims the image resolution isn't 1920x1080 - I think this is because MATLAB scales it before the function has a chance to 'get to it', as it were.

I could possibly make it work by just saving the image from each iteration of the loop and making a .gif out of it, but I'm not sure how I'd get that to display fullscreen and it would be a lot nicer to be able to control playback with VLC.

There's also ways to do this with normal plots:

```
set(hfig,'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
```

but this only works on objects created with plot commands, not image/imshow.

EDIT: OK I gave up and just made a .gif and it works in chrome's fullscreen mode, but a solution to this would still be nice since it seems like a fairly useful thing to know how to do.

Comment: Actually now that I've thought about it more it is easier to just make .avis from the frames with virtualDub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by using [psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/HomePage).  It is a much more appropriate starting point than Matlab's figure classes.  The package is built for Matlab and comes with a lot of demos which can easily be altered to generate your stimulus.

If you want to generate a movie, you can grab the full screen frames out of psychtoolbox with

```
imageArray = Screen('GetImage', wPtr, [0 0 1024 768]);
```

where wPtr is the pointer to a window you've created and the vector is the screen dimensions.  You can find more details on this [here](http://psychtoolbox.org/FaqScreenShots)

On the off chance that you're doing behavioral testing or psychophysics... I'd really stick with psychtoolbox and ignore VLC.